# Rails 3.1 CSS file loading twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets

I'm using Rails 3.1 RC. I wanted to load a CSS manually and not via the asset pipeline.

I've tried it like this and with a hand coded tag:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "/stylesheets/global" %>
```

For some reason FireBug shows me multiple get requests for the global.css file:

[image]

Rails bug? Me being stupid?

If anyone is wondering - I use CSSEdit a lot so couldnt work with the file inside the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you set the assets.enabled to false in config/application.rb?

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = false
```

Comment: No, as I wanted to have some css loaded with the asset-pipeline. I changed the assets.enabled flag to true as you suggested, which worked. But I wanted the pipeline assets loaded, so I changed it back to true, rebooted POW and now it's only loading one instance of global.css. Hmmm :-/

Answer (score 0):

I would guess this is caused by the same problem as described in [Rails 3.1 with Asset Pipeline, link_to :confirm message showing twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084087/rails-3-1-with-asset-pipeline-link-to-confirm-message-showing-twice).

You have precompiled assets in your development environment and `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>` will expand into multiple tags including each CSS file, one of them being `global.css`.